# Instead of external links we need internal links b/w merged workbooks, using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My aim is to merge all workbooks having multiple sheets from any specified folder to one workbook of multiple sheets. (I have attached code below)
The problem is I don’t want external links to be maintained, I tried to break these links using Macro, it’s also working. (just using breaklink command, attached below)

But what I exactly want is, After merging all workbooks in one workbook, instead of external links I need links b/w these merged sheets, so is there any strategy that I can use?

***Code for merge all workbooks into one workbook***

```
Sub merge()
    Dim FolderPath As String    
    Dim Filename As String    
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
   
    FolderPath = "C:\Users\Samiya jabbar\Desktop\test\"    
    Filename = Dir(FolderPath)    
    
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True

        For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets    
            Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)    
        Next Sheet  
    
        Workbooks(Filename).Close
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

***Break link***

```
Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook

If Not IsEmpty(wb.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)) Then
    For Each link In wb.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
        wb.BreakLink link, xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
    Next link
```

Comment: I don't get what exactly you are trying to do. If you need links between your sheets you need to create them from scratch.  If you want old links between the workbooks to persist in the new worksheets don't break them and try to `.Move` the sheets instead of copying them, this should actually move the links to the correct sheet too (if Microsoft didn't mess it up there). Give it a try at least.

Comment: Thanks, @Pᴇʜ for your response. I tried it using .move. still, I am getting the same output. let me explain more. For Example, I have 2 workbooks each contains 2 worksheets(for workbook 1, sheet a, sheet b & for workbook 2, sheet x & sheet y). (Sheet a) is connected to (sheet x) & (sheet b) is connected to (sheet y). I have merged these 2 workbooks using the above code. Now if I change data in (sheet a) of "original folder" it will also change data in (sheet x) of "merged workbook".

Comment: But if I try to change data in (sheet a) of "merged workbook" I am not getting any change in data in (sheet x) of "merged workbook". I want to break all the connections of the merged workbook from the workbooks of the " original folder" so that if I change something in the workbooks of the "original folder" it won't affect the data of my "merged workbook", but what I need is, if I change data of (sheet a) within the merged workbook than data of (sheet x) should be changed.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: I do not think that it would work in all the cases... If, for instance, a link address involves an workbook not having each sheets already moved, a reference will not exist.

Comment: I think that an appropriate strategy will firstly involve your first code to be a little modified. You can use `Move` instead of `Copy`, only to avoid closing the open workbooks. When all sheets will be moved, the workbook should automatically be closed. So, the workbook path and the sheet will be copied in each moved one. Then an iteration between the added sheets will extract formulas and check them against the workbook links. In another function the matching is searched and the new sheet name to be referenced will be found and the formula will be adapted accordingly.

Comment: In fact, I will start preparing an answer using the above described strategy. I think it would not take me to long...

Comment: It does work. The only thing you have to do is: First open **all** files. Then make all moves (no copies!) you want to do. And finally close the files you don't need anymore (don't save changes if you want to keep the original files too). This way all formula references get moved correcty (and point to the new workbook). I did that many times. There is no need to check any formuals manually.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: In this way it maybe would work, having all the time the possibility to change the reference. Now, it depends on how many such workbooks would be involved... I mean not a huge number.

Comment: @FaneDuru It is much harder to "extract" formulas and adjust them as you might think. You would need to be able to distinguish between something like `=Sheet2!A1` and `="Sheet2!A1"` and `=INDIRECT("Sheet2!A1")`. First and 3ʳᵈ need to be adjusted 2ⁿᵈ is just a string and must not be changed. You will need a decent code to solve that issue.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: I can agree it. Even the `INDIRECT` issue can be solved, but it should be a complicated solution. I did not start anything, since the sheet moving may work. One issue from your answer is still unclear for me: What the third issue should mean? If is it about closing the workbook after moving each sheets, I am afraid that if another open one targeting this one in a formula, it will not have a reference to be correctly moved, too. It probably will better involve closing all of them at the end...

Comment: @FaneDuru I actually meant to close them in the end. Maybe it was unclear, my bad, will edit that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to move all formula references correctly:

1. Open **all** files that are involved before you start moving.
2. Move your sheets (don't copy them).
3. After **all** movements are done: Close the files you don't need anymore (don't save changes if you want to keep the original files as before moving sheets).
4. Save your merged workbook.

---

Here is a proof of concept:

First we create 3 files with 2 workbooks each

```
Public Sub CreateTestWorkbooks()
    Const Path As String = "C:\Temp\MoveTest\"
    Const nWb As Long = 3 'amount of workbooks to create
    Const nWs As Long = 2 'amount of worksheets in each workbook
    
    Dim NewWb() As Workbook
    ReDim NewWb(1 To nWb) As Workbook
    
    Dim iWs As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'create workbooks
    Dim iWb As Long
    For iWb = 1 To nWb
        Set NewWb(iWb) = Application.Workbooks.Add
        For iWs = 1 To nWs - 1
            NewWb(iWb).Worksheets.Add After:=NewWb(iWb).Sheets(NewWb(iWb).Sheets.Count)
        Next iWs
        NewWb(iWb).SaveAs Filename:=Path & "File" & iWb & ".xlsx"
    Next iWb
    
    'write formulas
    Dim iFormula As Long
    For iWb = 1 To nWb
        For iWs = 1 To nWs
            NewWb(iWb).Worksheets(iWs).Range("A1").Value = "File" & iWb & ".xlsx " & "Sheet" & iWs
            For iFormula = 1 To nWb
                NewWb(iWb).Worksheets(iWs).Cells(iFormula, "B").Formula = "=[File" & iFormula & ".xlsx]Sheet" & iWs & "!$A$1"
            Next iFormula
        Next iWs
    Next iWb
    
    'save and close workbooks
    For iWb = 1 To nWb
        NewWb(iWb).Close SaveChanges:=True
    Next iWb
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "All " & nWb & " files were created.", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Then we consolidate them

```
Public Sub ConsolidateWorkbooks()
    Const Path As String = "C:\Temp\MoveTest\"
    
    Dim OpenedWorkbooks As Collection
    Set OpenedWorkbooks = New Collection
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'loop through files and open them all
    Dim File As String
    File = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
    Do While File <> vbNullString
        OpenedWorkbooks.Add Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & File, UpdateLinks:=True)
        File = Dir()
    Loop
    
    'create a new workbook to consolidate all worksheets
    Dim ConsolidateWb As Workbook
    Set ConsolidateWb = Application.Workbooks.Add
    
    'consolidate
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In OpenedWorkbooks
        Dim sh As Variant
        For Each sh In wb.Sheets
            sh.Move After:=ConsolidateWb.Sheets(ConsolidateWb.Sheets.Count)
            
            'this changes the constant in A1 of each sheet to make it
            'visible that formulas are now pointing to the new file (no formula changes are made here)
            With ConsolidateWb.Sheets(ConsolidateWb.Sheets.Count)
                .Range("A1").Value = "Consolidated.xlsx " & .Name
            End With
        Next sh
    Next wb
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ConsolidateWb.SaveAs Filename:=Path & "Consolidated.xlsx"
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this scenario, it is not complicated to adapt the existing code, but it does not change the initial reference after sheets moving. I have some 'Sheet1, Sheet2 etc.' in the tested files sheet names, which became 'Sheet1 (2), Sheet2 (2)` but I do not think this could be a reason. Could it be? Did you test it?

Comment: @FaneDuru first make sure all files are saved somewhere it does not work with new files that were not saved yet. Second: Yes I tried the following way: Created 2 files with `Sheet1` each. One has `=[File1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2` the other has `=[File2.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1` as formula. Then I create a new workbook and move the `Sheet1` from both files there. Their names automatically change to `Sheet1 (2)` and `Sheet1 (3)` as there is a `Sheet1` in the new file already. Formulas change to `='Sheet1 (3)'!$A$1` and `='Sheet1 (2)'!$A$2` pointing tho the new consolidated workbook. Both files are autoclosed.

Comment: I used four such files. I have them in a test folder from some time. Three of them having one single sheet (csv type) and the third one having three sheets (xlsx type). In the third sheet of the last one I created a formula `='C:\Teste VBA Excel\TestCSV\[Sheet1.csv]Sheet1'!$B$1` which has not been updated to the newly 'Sheet1 (2)` created sheet after moving the sheet containing the formula. I tried it many times... A formula targeting a csv cell should  not be a problem, I think.

Comment: I saved the csv file as xlsx, then I targeted this workbook in the formula `='C:\Teste VBA Excel\TestCSV\[Sheet1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$1` and it behaves exactly the same. After moving the sheet, the link has not been updated to the newly created sheet by moving the original one. But if it will be useful for @Samia Jabbar this would be perfect! I am out of ideas about other ways to test it... I will also try with the files not being open programmatically. They maybe need some time to update the link..

Comment: I tried the code in the above explained way (workbooks manually open) and the link did not change. I cannot imagine what I can doing wrong...

Comment: Thanks @PEH , this strategy is effective .

Comment: @FaneDuru I added a proof of concept. Check it out. All formulas point to the consolidated workbook in the end.

Comment: Thanks @FaneDuru for your response. I tried it by replacing .copy  to .move , along with workbooks manually open. It's working.

Comment: @SamiaJabbar it works with automatically opened workbooks too as shown in my `Sub ConsolidateWorkbooks`

Comment: Of course, it works! After testing your solution I want back to my trials, in order to use this new path (maybe something paranormal with the path...) and I could see that I built my (simple) test sub using `Copy` instead of `Move`. I could swear I used `Move`... Voted up.

Comment: @FaneDuru Ah well, there we have the explanation ^^

Comment: I could not sleep without an explanation... :)